# How to share datas between Ruby and c?

Tags: c, ruby, linux, communication

There is a Ruby process and has a string var named "switch", and the "switch" will be updated by user.  There are also 2 C daemon process, which need to access the "switch" in a loop and decide the logic in runtime, how to deal with this case ? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A socket (or a common file) can be used as a pipe between them.

Answer (score 2):

Given your description, it sounds like you need a message queue. Something like RabbitMQ should work. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html for details.

Comment: Is there any message queue server based C ?

Comment: RabbitMQ has a C based client API

Comment: I do not plan to use Erlang, because i am not clear with it :)